# express deprecated and RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE] in React Project

Tags: reactjs, express, switch-statement, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

With my React cruise ship project, on my [reviews-part branch](https://github.com/JamesPrenticez/cruise-ships/tree/reviews-part) I am getting the following error when running npm run dev for the localhost.

[image: NPM Run Dev Error for ShipsList on Command Line]

It says that express is deprecated , what does this mean ?
It is also pointing to my [ships route](https://github.com/JamesPrenticez/cruise-ships/blob/reviews-part/server/routes/ships.js)

and on my localhost these are the errors
[image]

I need help to understand why these errors are happening.
If anyone has any suggestions that may help, that will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't say that Express is deprecated, it says that `res.send(status, body)` is deprecated. More specifically, it means that `res.send()` should only be passed *one* argument.

In your code, you're using two arguments:

```
res.status(500).send('something went wrong', err)
```

Express is trying to parse the first argument (`'something went wrong'`) as an HTTP status code, which it obviously isn't, hence the `ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE` error.

One solution would be to add the error message to the string.

```
res.status(500).send(`something went wrong: ${ err.message }`)
```